# JPA Inheritance Table_per_class SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I got a SQLSyntaxErrorException every time I start my application.
I don't have any experience with jpa inheritence
and have no idea where the tables are created.
Does anyone know more of this and is willing to help?

**Exception**

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-09-17 18:16:13.471--ServerSession(2032898330)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered ")" at line 1, column 20.
Error Code: 30000
Call: CREATE TABLE ITEM ()
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE ITEM ()")
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Boredom2.0PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domain.item.Book</class>
    <class>domain.item.Movie</class>
    <class>domain.item.TvShow</class>
    <class>domain.item.Franchise</class>
    <class>domain.item.Comicbook</class>
    <class>domain.item.VideoGame</class>
    <class>domain.item.Manga</class>
    <class>domain.item.Genre</class>
    <class>domain.item.Item</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/BoredomDB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Item**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Item extends IEntity implements Serializable{
```

**IEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IEntity {
```

Comment: `Item` is defined as `abstract` yet is also `@Entity`. That makes little sense since it can never have instances of that type. Make `Item` a `@MappedSuperclass` or define the `@Id` field on it. The tables are being created in your DATASTORE (Apache Derby, that you defined in the persistence.xml)

Comment: I had Item as a `MappedSuperClass` but it has a ManyToMany-mapping right now.
The `@Id` field is in `IEntity`

Comment: In which case the table `ITEM` (if it has to exist) should have a column for the id column with that inheritance strategy. So raise a bug on your chosen JPA provider

Comment: I don't have a reason (yet?) for the `item`-table to exist, but I thought `mappedSuperClass` didn't work with a manyToMany-mapping?